# How to print specific elements of a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to print the nth value of a list, in this case an integer. However every time I get the entire list as output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

from this code:

```
numbers1 = []
numbers1.insert(0, list(map(int, input().split(" "))))


print(numbers1[0])
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I don't understand why it isn't printing the first element, numbers1[0].

Comment: can you write, what are the contents of numbers1 after insertion?

Comment: `n`th value of list is `your_list[n-1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inserting a list onto a list so your list actually looks like this:

```
[ [1, 2, 3] ]
```

What you want can be accomplished by doing:

```
numbers1 = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
```

or

```
numbers1.extend(list(map(int, input().split(" "))))
```

However, I would advise against using `map` with input in this case because it obfuscates your input and you don't usually want to do that. Instead, try this:

```
userInput = input()
numbers1.extend( [int(s) for s in userInput.split(" ")] )
```

This code does the same thing but as a list comprehension, which avoids the call to `map` and the call to `list`, reducing overhead while improving readability. This is also more Pythonic IMHO.

Comment: This is true and the extend solution is the right way to go I think (+1). However the whole thing is ugly to write on one row. I'd create an extra valuable to make it more readable.

Comment: Yeah, I'll edit my response to show some cleaner code